# How do I get Azure to return the 'Accept-Ranges' and 'Content-Encoding' headers in the response when a file is requested?

Tags: azure, http-headers, blob

I am using Azure blob storage, and when I do a GET request for a file I want the response to include headers for 'Accept-Ranges' and 'Content-Encoding'.

I have ran the following code against my blob server to first allow these:

```
var url = new Uri(String.Format("https://yourblob.blob.core.windows.net"));
var credentials = new StorageCredentials("accountname", "key");
var client = new CloudBlobClient(url, credentials);

var corsRule = new CorsRule();

corsRule.ExposedHeaders.Add("Accept-Ranges");
corsRule.ExposedHeaders.Add("Content-Encoding");
corsRule.ExposedHeaders.Add("Content-Length");
corsRule.ExposedHeaders.Add("Content-Type");

corsRule.AllowedHeaders.Add("Accept-Ranges");
corsRule.AllowedHeaders.Add("Content-Encoding");
corsRule.AllowedHeaders.Add("Content-Length");
corsRule.AllowedHeaders.Add("Content-Type");

var serviceProperties = CloudBlobClient.GetServiceProperties();
serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Clear();
serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(corsRule);
client.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
```

This seems to have worked because before when I ran the following Javascript on the object returned I was getting an error saying `Refused to get unsafe header "Accept-Ranges"`, I no longer get this error:

```
var fullRequestXhr = networkManager.getRequestXhr(fullRequestXhrId);
if (fullRequestXhr.getResponseHeader('Accept-Ranges') !== 'bytes') {
    return;
}
```

But the header isn't present either. I found [this blog post](http://programmerpayback.com/2013/01/30/hosting-progressive-download-videos-on-azure-blobs/) which suggested changing the **DefaultServiceVersion** of my azure blob server to "2012-02-12". I have done this and am still not seeing the needed headers.

I need these for a library I am using (pdf.js) which allows, if these are present, to load a pdf file in chunks. Maybe there is something I need to do to the file before it is uploaded?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Two things. 1) What happens when you instruct storage service to return all headers by doing something like `corsRule.ExposedHeaders.Add("*");` and 2) Can you trace the request in Fiddler and see if the response header includes these headers? I ran into similar issue with `Last-Modified` response header where it was returned by storage service however it was coming as null in my jQuery function when I did `getResponseHeader('Last-Modified').

Comment: Weirdly ExposedHeaders.Add("*") didn't include `Accept-Ranges` etc, I had to explicitly specify it to work. And have checked in fiddler, they aren't there.

Comment: Have you solved it? Im having the same issue.